# findOrCreate creates duplicates

Tags: asynchronous, each, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I'm using [oracle adapter](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle), `async.each` and [`findOrCreate`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/findOrCreate.html) to transfer some data from oracle to my postgres db:

```
//simplified version
oracle.select(sql, [], function(err, results) {
    async.each(results, function(add_me, async_cb){
        model_to_add.findOrCreate(
            {not_id_field: add_me.value},
            {required_fields: add_me.values}
        ).exec(function add_me_cb(err, record){
            if (record && !err){
                async_cb();
            }
        });
    });
})
```

My sql query returns multiple, not unique values for `not_id_field`. But I want it to be unique in my postgres db. I thought `finOrCreate` is the great thing to use. But it somehow fails to find a record.

Was I wrong? Or maybe there's something I'm missing? `sails.js` documentation isn't really helpful : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with me - I didn't really understand how `async.each` works and that it is executed for every item in the array almost at the same time. I switched to `async.eachSeries` and now it works fine.